# Access 2010: multiple "problem inserts" for one user

Tags: ms-access

I know the title looks a little faque, but my technical english is not as good as would it to be.

My question. I'm designing a kind of work order form with access database. The pretty standard database I can manage, but my problems starts when I want multiple entries for one customer.

For example:

Customer Chris with Id 1 has a problem, he has a BSOD which is fixed. Customer Chris has a new problem some weeks later with his videocard, which will be fixed later ofcourse (;-))

The info above needs to be stored in the access database. Do I need a second table? I really don't have a idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least two tables, one for customers and one for problems. The problem table should include such information as customer id, date fixed and fix applied. You may also want to include the engineer, in which case you will also need an employees table, and so it grows.

You may wish to read http://r937.com/relational.html

Comment: I understand that, but how can I connect these two? Should there be a relationship between both Table1 Id and Table2 Id?

Comment: Yes. You relate customers to problems on the customer id. I have also added an extra note to my answer.

Comment: Great, I'll jump in this infor thumbs up!

Comment: ...and to work with the data, you'd use forms and subforms, with the form likely being based on the Customer, and the subform displaying the problems (with LinkMaster/LinkChild properties defined to filter the subform to the problems related to the currently-displayed customer).